# Select cell greater than and lesser than some dynamic values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I want to select cells which is greater than a and lesser than b, where a and b are values of some input box.

Here is my code:

```
$a = $("#box1").val();
$b = $("#box2").val();
$("#table tr").each(function(){
$(this).find("td:lt("+$a+"):gt("+$b+")").css("background-color","#FF00FF");
});
```

But it is not highlighting any column

Comment: no column is highlighted

Comment: u want to select through `index` value ???

Comment: yes i want to select through index value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to highlight your column through `index` value,you can use `slice`

http://api.jquery.com/slice/

```
$(this).slice(start,end).css("background-color","#FF00FF");
```

**Full Code**

```
$a = $("#box1").val();
$b = $("#box2").val();
$("#table tr").each(function(){
 $(this).find("td").slice($a,$b).css("background-color","#FF00FF");
});
```

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/rynhe/e4VbB/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `slice` method for selection from a to b index:

```
var a = $("#box1").val();
var b = $("#box2").val();
$("#table tr").slice(a,b).css("background-color","#FF00FF");
```

Comment: You can add check `if (a>b) {t = b; b = a; a = t;} else {t = a; a = b; b = t;}` if you want %)

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the text values to int and then use them in `gt` and `lt`

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4VbB/2/)**

```
$a = parseInt($("#box1").val());
$b = parseInt($("#box2").val());
$("#table tr").each(function(){
$(this).find("td:lt("+$a+"):gt("+$b+")").css("background-color","#FF00FF");
});
```

Comment: Milind,the answer you post differs from the one in working fiddle,the answer you provide does not work,the one in working fiddle have static values in `lt()` and `gt()` which i am not looking for.